# C# Assembly.LoadFrom(myNetworkPath) throws FileLoadException

Tags: c#, networking, dll, .net-assembly

I'm developing a small demo that assemble class from DLL file.

This is my code:

```
string path = @"\\192.168.1.3\shareFolder\testzwm.dll";
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

It always throws `FileLoadException`

However if I change to :

```
string path = @"C:\testzwm.dll";
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

It works.

Does it mean I cannot load dll from network path? I think it doesn't make sense.
I have read/write authority in \192.168.1.3\shareFolder

If I change the first path to \192.168.1.3\shareFolder\testzwmWRONG.dll, it throws `FileNotFoundException` , not the same with FileLoadException.

So I guess it's some security problem

Any help is so appreciated.

------------------EDIT------------------
My project is Windows Form Application.

Comment: Is your IDE running with as administrator?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328274/load-assembly-from-network-location-c-sharp-net4

Comment: @IDeveloper, yes, I can directly acces \\192.168.1.3\shareFolder in broswer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your config file

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In addition read this article 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/06/08/more-implicit-uses-of-cas-policy-loadfromremotesources.aspx

Comment: Thanks, my project is Windows Form Application. So where should I add the tag: loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"

Comment: @JimZ To your config file. (app.config in the solution that becomes your.exe.config when you deploy) See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Mike Beeler, you saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

While Mike's answer is correct it can have some potentially undesired side-effects.  Enabling `loadFromRemoteSources` changes the security configuration of your entire application to allow loading *any* remote assembly.

One alternative is to load the content of the file into a byte array, then use `Assembly.Load` to load it:

```
public static Assembly LoadRemoteAssembly(string filename)
{
    byte[] asmdata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    return Assembly.Load(asmdata);
}
```

While you are still bypassing application security by tricking the .NET framework into loading an assembly from the network, you aren't opening your application up to *every* assembly on the network.

It might seem like a trivial difference but if you have to poke holes in your security layers, try to make them *little* holes.