# How to execute with a copied dll from another machine - c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to provide a colleague with a dll that is from my build so she can execute with the changes i have made. Unfortunately she gets the following error

> The system was unable to launch the requested screen. --->
>   Unable to display screen.
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///name.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
>   supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) --->
>   System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly
>   from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be
>   sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of
>   the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load
>   may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the
>   assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch

Now if she were trying to run it in visual studio i could set the loadFromRemoteSources switch - however this dll is replacing a dll in an install version on a vagrant box. How can i enable the dll to run in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238714/net-local-assembly-load-failed-with-cas-policy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328274/load-assembly-from-network-location have some potential solutions. What did you try from there?

Comment: tried both of those approaches already - the unblock button isnt present